# How do I set up disk quotas over LDAP on CentOs?

Tags: centos, ldap, quota, disk-space-utilization

I've been google-ing for some time and I haven't been able to find any resources or hints on the subject.

I am wondering if it is possible to do so, if so how? Any nudge in right direction will be appricated.

I do know that if you download and install "Linux Quota" from source, you'll get some perl scripts which are supposed to aid with the matter. But there is as far as I know absolutely no good documentation to help you along the way.

I am also running a NFS server from the same machine.

*Note: This is for a university assignment, so I might be totally stupid for asking this question. I am trying to explore the options. If there is a better way of solving this, please do tell.*

Edit: Here is a link to the site of [Linux Quota](http://linuxquota.sourceforge.net/). They do include a LDAP schema, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around I finally came to a solution.

While it doesn't directly answers the question it does provdide a better and more easily manageable solution.

RPCBIND is can handle quotas remotely. That means just by installing *quota*, then restarting NFS you're good to go. (You'll need to set up quotas normally of course. There is a lot of resources on the internet covering this topic. Google it)

Ultimately that means not using LDAP for handling quotas, but let NFS handle that part with an added module.